# Launch Raspberry Pi after sudo shutdown?

Tags: linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I shutdown my Pi 2 (model B)  with `sudo shutdown - h now`

However after this the only way to boot it is to remove and insert the power cable.  Any better way to do this?

Comment: You cant do this programmatically. RPi2 has a special holes P6 where you can soldier PINs and use it as reset. Take a look at this image [image](http://raspi.tv/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/DSC_3661-e1355784030259.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps you can put it to suspend/hibernate use "Wake on LAN" to wake it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so - there is no reset/power button.

Consider removing the charger from the wall, or the other end of the usb charger rather than stress the tiny micro socket on the pi

Comment: It has two pads which can be shorted to reboot

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reboot rather than shutdown either of these may be what you are looking for:

```
sudo reboot
sudo shutdown -r now
```